# XCode 12, ios 14, Cant Copy Paste in simulator for ios version below ios 14

Tags: ios, simulator, ios14, xcode12

I try copy pasting to my ios simulator, it's working in my ios 14. But when I switched to other simulator with the previous ios version it has issues: First it wont paste at all, later it will paste some text which I didn't even copy in the first place, in my case it's paste this instead: `@available(ios 13.0,*)`
Does anyone have this issue too?

Comment: Same issue here!

Comment: Same issue here!